# How to make my selectlist scroll to bottom?

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have created a multi-select list, input text box and a add button. User can insert the new option in the multiselect list through input box and add button. I have created an example fiddle also :

http://jsbin.com/exuwis/7/edit

I have used knockout.js in my example.The select list is defined with "size="5". After I get more than 5 entries in the list, I can't see any new entries without manually scrolling to the bottom. I want that when user enter any new entry in the list the scroll bar automatically moves to the bottom of the list. How can i do this ?

Comment: Have you tried selecting the last selected item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider adding the new option on top of the other options.

Not a good practice to auto scroll content.

Use

`self.CourseOptions.unshift(self.OptionToAdd());`

instead of

`self.CourseOptions.push(self.OptionToAdd());`

to insert item at the begging of the array.

Answer (score 2):

add bindingHandler:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.scrollDown = {
update: function (elem, valueAccessor) {
    var shouldBeSelected = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
    if (shouldBeSelected) {
        //scroll
        $(elem).scrollTop(val);
        // back to previous state
        var boundProperty = valueAccessor();
        if (ko.isWriteableObservable(boundProperty))
            boundProperty(false);
    }
}};
```

add data-bind to scrolling element:

```
  select data-bind="scrollDown: scrollDown ...
```

add to MainModel:

```
self.scrollDown = ko.observable(false);
self.CourseOptions.subscribe(function(){
  setTimeout(function () { 
    self.scrollDown(true); 
  }, 0); 
});
```

example: http://jsbin.com/exuwis/14/edit